# To get value from 2 column in single row in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

could somebody help me, as I just very new in PHP

**Description**:-

- In my table, I have 3 column: **Adult, Child, Totalpax**
- I just give the value into Adult & Child column and leave Totalpax column empty
- Then, I try to make a calculation so that Totalpax filed get the amount from Adult + Child column

**What have I do**:-

- Below is my code..
- The problem is - this code give me the total number from my table.
- BUT - I just want to get the value just from singe row..
- Is my code below wrong? if so, how to create a code, so that I just get the amount from single row?..

Thank in advance..

**My Code**:-

```
<?php 
foreach($pdo->query("SELECT SUM(adult+child) FROM test WHERE testID = testID") as $totalpax) {
echo $totalpax['SUM(adult+cwhild)'];}
?>
```

Comment: You are giving it a condition that is true for every row: `testID = testID`. If you meant to select only the value for one specific testID, have a look at how to [parametrize the query through a prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: And as a side note, `Totalpax` should not be a column in your database. Anything that can be calculated from other table data while selecting should not be stored. If you store that number, then you have to keep updating it any time you update `adult` or `child`, which just adds complexity to your update operation and might lead to inconsistent state in your database if you forget to update one of the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT SUM(adult+child)
FROM test
WHERE testID = testID
```

Start with the `WHERE` clause.  It is comparing a problem to itself -- so this returns information from all rows where `testID` is not `NULL`.

What information does it return?  That information is the `SUM()` of two columns.  This is an aggregation query that returns one row, which has one column which is the sum of `adult + child` on basically all rows in the table.

> Then, I try to make a calculation so that Totalpax filed get the amount from Adult + Child column.

As you have described the problem, you want an *`update`* not a `select`.  That would be:

```
update test
    set Totalpax = adult + child;
```

Comment: After 'struggling' trying all advises, finally I successful get what I want. Thank to all that give the advises and I most appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` is an aggregate function which totals all the rows for the given expression.

To get a value for each row separately simply add them:

```
SELECT adult+child as total FROM test
```

And then

```
echo $totalpax['total']
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Adyson..I'll try to adjust my code

Comment: No problem. If you find the answer helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click on the tick mark next to the best answer, so it turns green) - thanks.